# How to lock the screen when the laptop lid is closed in Ubuntu 23.04?

Tags: lock-screen, lid, 23.04

I have the following entries in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`:

```
HandleLidSwitch=lock
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=lock
```

but it doesn't help even after reboot.